# Custom button style is not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to style a button, but it ends up not showing when I apply the custom style, only its content (the button's text) is visible. This is how I declare my style:

```
    <Color x:Key="NormalColor" A="255" R="60" G ="158" B="184"/>
    <Color x:Key="HoverColor" A="255" R="74" G ="177" B="204"/>
    <Color x:Key="PressedColor" A="255" R="26" G ="115" B="138"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="{StaticResource NormalColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBrush" Color="{StaticResource HoverColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="{StaticResource PressedColor}" />

    <Style x:Key="FlatButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="Content"/>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource HoverBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />                                
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

And here is how I use it:

```
<Button Content="Connect" Command="model:GlobalCommands.ConnectToDBCommand" Style="{StaticResource FlatButton}"/>
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your `ControlTemplate` that would use `Background`. Put your `ContentPresenter` inside `Border` (for example) and use `TemplateBinding` to bind its `Background`

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="Content"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @dkozl's answer, you should add `TemplateBinding`s to any properties within the `Button.ControlTemplate` that you may want to set from outside the `Button.ControlTemplate`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding
    BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

Then you could do this:

```
<Button Content="Connect" Command="model:GlobalCommands.ConnectToDBCommand" 
    Style="{StaticResource FlatButton}" BorderBrush="Blue" BordeThickness="5" />
```